# How to join two queries in one and get results in a single query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT SUM(commission) as regularincome FROM `tbl_member_commission` where mem_id=2 AND MONTH(cdate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())

SELECT SUM(commission) as crowdfund FROM `tbl_member_comm_month` where mem_id=2 AND MONTH(cdate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
```

note:- both of tables have these same column names : commission, mem_id, cdate

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only record in each subquery, you can use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
 select a.regularincome, b.crowdfund
 FROM
    (SELECT SUM(commission) as regularincome FROM `tbl_member_commission` where mem_id=2 AND MONTH(cdate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())) as a
    cross join 
    (SELECT SUM(commission) as crowdfund FROM `tbl_member_comm_month` where mem_id=2 AND MONTH(cdate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())) as b
```

Comment: you forget a thing that i want first commission as regularincome and second as crowdfund

Comment: You expect to have both records in the same row, or two different rows but sorted in a different way?

Comment: i want them in a same row